# How can I install the p-rabbitmq service on my local pcfdev?

Tags: rabbitmq, pcfdev, bosh

I am running the pcfdev `v11.2.0` locally on my laptop.
When I try to list the marketplace it is empty.

```
$ cf marketplace
Getting services from marketplace in org cfdev-org / space cfdev-space as admin...
OK

No service offerings found
```

I understand that I need a `service-broker` for this but am not sure where I can get one from. Also, once I install/deploy the `service broker` how can I create a service from it for rabbitmq ?

I did explore the `bosh` route too and all I could find was the [multitenant broker](https://bosh.io/releases/github.com/pivotal-cf/cf-rabbitmq-multitenant-broker-release?all=1) for rabbitmq.

I was able to create a CUPS for my local rabbitmq running on my laptop, but would like to get the standard (ie non-CUPS) service for rabbitmq working.
Since this is just for local development, a single node rabbitmq would be fine.

Please advise/suggest some options if you have worked this out already.

TIA.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am a maintainer of CF Dev. Installing additional services is a topic covered in the [FAQ](https://github.com/cloudfoundry-incubator/cfdev/blob/5ddd9c1fe628a12386bc62e105b773ad676defd8/FAQ.md#the-only-service-available-is-mysql-how-do-i-get-access-to-pivotal-apps-manager-rabbitmq-redis-spring-cloud-services).

> **The only service available is mysql. How do I get access to pivotal apps manager, rabbitmq, redis, spring-cloud-services?**
>
> A separate asset is needed. You can download the correct asset for your platform at https://network.pivotal.io/products/pcfdev. Then you perform a start with the downloaded asset specified via the `-f` flag, like so: `cf dev start -f ./pcfdev-v*.tgz`.

Comment: Do I need to use the `-f` flag each and every time I start `cf` ? I am using `pcfdev-v1.2.0-darwin.tgz` on my mac.

Comment: Yes, you do need to use the `-f` flag.

Comment: Works perfectly !